# C++ Передача значений из файла в массив

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Хочу брать из файла числа и вписывать в элементы массива. Почему не работает? И как работает `while (file >> k),  while (file >> m)`, если я правильно написал и можно ли использовать разные перемненные или достаточно одной?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
{
ifstream file("f.txt");
ofstream fileout("g.txt");
int count = 0, m;
while (file >> m)
    count++;
if (count % 2 == 1)
{
    cout << "Ne 4etno. Input 4etno." << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int *a = new int[count];
int i = 0, k;
while (file >> k)
{
    file >> a[i];
    i++;
}

for (int j = 0; j <count; j++) {
    cout << a[j] << " ";
}
file.close();
fileout.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: А смысл читать 2 раза? Сразу читайте и записывайте, если нечетно - удалите выходной файл...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перемотайте файл на начало:

```
...

file.clear();
file.seekg(0);

int *a = new int[count];
int i = 0, k;
while (file >> k)
{
    a[i] = k; // !!
    i++;
}
...
```

N.B.

1. Вы не закрываете файлы, когда выходите из функции при нечетном `count`.
2. Вы ничего не пишете в `ofstream`.

*Update*

А, и если Вам надо считывать пары чисел, то:

```
while (file >> k && file >> m)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, а что делает `file.clear();
file.seekg(0);`

Comment: @Андрей переводит файл в состояние, как будто Вы его только что открыли

Comment: Вроде же можно записывать в один и тот же файл? 
То бишь вместо while `(file >> k),  while (file >> m)`
писать `while (file >> k),  while (file >> k)` или `while (file >> m),  while (file >>m)`

Comment: @Андрей не понял вопроса. Вы открываете `fileout`, но ничего туда не пишете.

Comment: в fileout я буду вписывать чередующиеся числа, реализую позже, мне главное с file-ом разобраться. Я имел ввиду, что когда я считываю файл пишу цикл типа `while (file >> k)`, а в другом цикле уже меняю переменную K на M. Вроде же можно использовать ту же переменную, она у нас типа буфера, верно?

Comment: @Андрей Да. Логика того, в какие переменные читаются числа из файла, - полностью на Ваше усмотрение.